# Why does wordpress .htacces kill all subdomain sessions

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

I installed wordpress in the root of my server. When the bundled .htaccess file is in the root subdomain sessions stop working. Below is the contents of the .htaccess.

```
  # BEGIN WordPress
  <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
  </IfModule>
  # END WordPress
```

Sorry .htaccess are all greek to me. Why does it break sessions, how to fix?

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to set `RewriteEngine Off` in effected subdomains